# WCF Service. Can't host in IIS7

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, iis-7

I have a very simple WCF service and I am trying to host it in my local IIS. I get this error all the time:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

I tried to change Application Pool to Classic, but still doesn't work. I tried bunch of other web sites but no success.

Can anyone help on this please.

**UPDATE 1:**

I have my dll and pdb file in the bin folder and I have web.config like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment>
      <serviceActivations>
        <add factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory" relativeAddress="./HelloWorldService.svc" service="MyWCFServices.HelloWorldService" />
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Then added a new project in IIS showing the path to the folder which contains dll. 
I get error when go to this link: `http://mycomputername/HelloWorldService/HelloWorldService.svc.`

**UPDATE 2:**

In my computer .NET 3.5.1 feature was turned off. I turned it on. Then I got this error: 
  [image]
then I changed .net versions in Application pool to 4.0.30319. After these changes still same error:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

Comment: how did you set it up?

Comment: Are you trying to access the svc file? In VS, if you set the default host instead of IIS and you try to browse the svc file, does WCF client come up?

Comment: @giordano261 yes I tried to host service in VS(IISExpress) and it works fine.

Comment: This might sound like a dumb question, but do you have .net 3.5.1 features turned on? This will be required for WCF to work in IIS.

Comment: @giordano261 actually it was off. I turned it on. Then I got different error. See my update.

Comment: In IIS at the server level, `ISAPI and CGI Restrictions`, is v4 enabled?

Comment: Perhaps another dumb question, but worth checking, just to be sure: Have yout turned on `HttpActivation`? (Found under `Asp.Net -> WCF Services` using "Turn Windows features on or off").

Comment: @JoeEnos I don't see v4.0 in there. Should I add it?

Comment: If v4 isn't there, you'll probably need to install it. From the command line, `c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i` should install it. But if you had the 4.0 app pool already, that doesn't make sense. Maybe something got funked up with the install. You can always run this command again - it's safe.

Comment: @JoeEnos I run that in command line and it added two things on that list. I allowed both of them. Now it is working. Thanks you very much. I took me almost a day to make this work.

Comment: Coolio. I'll add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comment chain:

In IIS at the server level, ISAPI and CGI Restrictions, you'll need to enable v4.

If v4 isn't there, you'll need to install/register ASP.NET v4 with IIS:

```
c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```